# Ways to save midi-cc-mapping in FL Studio?

Tags: midi, fl-studio, vsti, map

First of all, i've already found a way to do it by myself: open some VST/VSTi, select parameter u need - move it & connect it via Multilink - Last tweaked control (or do the same via Midi Learn, if plugin has it). Next, when u connected all the needed params, save it via "Save preset as", and then when u need same cc-mapping just load previously saved ".fst" file into another plugin-instance.

And, well, it works. But problem is that when u save .fst-file, it saves all the parameters, not only cc-map, but everything. So when u load it, every parameter gets replaced.

So i wonder - is there a smarter, more convenient way to save ONLY midi-cc-mappings, without all other stuff??